# @AfterClass is not calling immediately after class is executed in TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I have 2 test classes and each contains around 3 tests in them. 3rd test case depends on 2nd test case and 2nd test case depends on 1st testcase in each class.

Class1:

```
public class MyTest1 extends BaseCase{
    @Test
    public void Test1(){
    System.out.println("Test1");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "Test1")
    public void Test2(){
    System.out.println("Test2");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "Test2")
    public void Test3(){
    System.out.println("Test3");
    }
}
```

Class2:

```
public class MyTest2 extends BaseCase{
    @Test
        public void Test1(){
        System.out.println("Test1");
        }

        @Test(dependsOnMethods = "Test1")
        public void Test2(){
        System.out.println("Test2");
        }

        @Test(dependsOnMethods = "Test2")
        public void Test3(){
        System.out.println("Test3");
        }
}
```

I have written @BeforeClass and @AfterClass in BaseCase class. When I run the test cases from testng.xml file @AfterClass is invoked after two classes are executed. But, @BeforeClass is working fine.

I would have to execute @AfterClass after each class is completed.

Please let me know if you have any ideas on it.

Testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestCases">
    <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"></parameter>
    <parameter name="environment" value="qa"></parameter>
    <test name="BulkUserImport">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.MyTest1"></class>
            <class
                name="com.MyTest2"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Can you please show your testng.xml file

Comment: Updated with testng.xml

Comment: Kindly clarify, There are only two classes as you define. So when you want to execute @AfterClass method? After Completing first class? You are mentioning "@AfterClass after each class is completed." So what you mean by each class ? You want to execute it after each class or test?

Comment: I am getting the response as expected. Before and After class is executed correctly.

Comment: <classes>
            <class name="com.MyTest1"></class>
</Classes>
<Classes>
            <class
                name="com.MyTest2"></class>
        </classes>. Please separate your classes tag into two class

Comment: When I add multiple <classes> tag in single <test> i am getting below error: The content of element type "test" must match "(method-selectors?,parameter*,groups?,packages?,classes?)". @AnkurSingh

Comment: I tried as below then it is working fine. 
<suite name="TestCases">
 <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"></parameter>
 <parameter name="environment" value="qa"></parameter>

 <test name="test1">
  <classes>
   <class name="com.MyTest1"></class>
  </classes>
 </test>

<test name="test2">
  
   <class
    name="com.MyTest2"></class>
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>

Comment: So it's working now right